# r.mapcalc in GRASS GIS fails to mask rasters

Tags: raster, grass-gis, overlapping-features, r.mapcalc

I have a raster binary map (0-1) where 0 represents unsuitable areas (violet) and 1 represents suitable areas (yellow). I want to crop another raster (red) based on this suitability (for several species in a loop).

[image]

In this example, basically every cell of the red raster (apart from few cells in the south of Spain) should be inside the suitable area. This is what I tried:

```
wd=/home/grassdata/myname
g.region -p raster=EU_3035 res=10000 

while read sp;
do
echo "===================== LOAD $sp SUITABILITY AND RASTER =======" 
r.in.gdal --o input=$wd'/'$sp'.tif' output=$sp'_bin'
r.in.gdal --o input=$wd'/'$sp'_red.tif' output=$sp'_red'
echo "===================== CREATE A MASK =======" 
r.mapcalc --o "MASK = if(${sp}_bin == 1,1,null())" 
echo "===================== CREATE A RASTER FOR $sp WITHOUT THE UNSUITABLE CELLS ======="
r.mapcalc --o "${sp}_red_suit = ${sp}_red"
echo "===================== SAVE RASTER ======="
r.out.gdal --o input=$sp'_red_suit' output=$wd'/'$sp'_red_suit.tif' format=GTiff
echo "===================== REMOVE MASK ======="
r.mask -r
done < $wd/sp_list.txt
```

To double check, I tried to save the `MASK`, which looks good:
[image]

Then I checked the output (`$sp'_red_suit.tif'`), and in this example almost every cell from the red raster should have been there. This is how the original raster (red) and the output (green) look like:
[image]

I cannot understand what's going on. Some of the green cells overlap with the red ones, others don't. All of the green cells are inside the suitable area (yellow), which is good, but the red ones that are inside the yellow are should stay in the output as well. Am I doing something wrong with `r.mapcalc` command?
EPSG is 3035, computational region is set, resolution is 10km, all the rasters are correctly projected as far as I see. I'm using GRASS GIS 7.8.7

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks correct to me...So I don't have a good explanation for the weird results.

Comment: What is in the sp_list.txt file? I guess you have multiple species maps? Do you have, in the end, a list of `*_res_suit.tif` in the $wd?  Is the map with the green areas a merge of all species? Or a single species?

Comment: I think I found the problem - the $sp_bin raster had a different resolution because it was not resampled. Thanks!